# How to Remove Non-Third Party Authentication ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth

My goal (if possible) is to be able to remove the authentication from an ASP.NET Core Web Application while keeping third-party ones. For example, remove the register and log in with username and password features *but* keep Google, FaceBook, etc. third party authentication. I have no clue if this is possible or if you have to keep your application's authentication but after scouring the internet a while I can't find an answer.

Comment: Do you know how it is configured right now to support all these authentications? You might want to remove configuration which you don't need.

Comment: @Chetan I have the default configuration for authentication + a facebook third party. My goal would be to make it so you have to use Facebook's third-party OAuth to log in and not a username and password